# C thread creation in a 20 line program. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to run a short program that creates three threads within a for loop, each of them writing "inside" to the screen. This is happening with Cygwin running on both XP and Vista on different machines. This is the current code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
using namespace std;
void* printInside(void* arg);

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, printInside, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
void* printInside(void* arg)
{
    cout << "inside";
        return 0;
}
```

And it doesn't work. If I add a cout to the inside of the for loop, it appears to slow it down into working.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << "";
    pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, printInside, 0);
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this is the case?

EDIT:

I've gotten responses to add a join after the loop

```
int main()
 {
     pthread_t threads[3];
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, printInside, 0);
    }
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        void* result;
        pthread_join(threads[i],&result);
    }
}
 void* printInside(void* arg)
 {
    cout << "inside";
    return 0;
}
```

But it still doesn't work, is the join done wrong?

FIXED

> > "Output is usually buffered by the standard library. It is flushed in certain circumstances but sometimes you have to do it manually. So even if the threads run and produce output you won't see it unless you flush it."

Comment: +1 for a well structured question.

Comment: *FYI*: Sending output to `std::cout` is not thread-safe. You'll need some sort of locks to protect the `cout` data structures.

Comment: @Robᵩ : Only in C++03. C++11, §27.4.1/4: "*Concurrent access to a synchronized standard iostream object’s formatted and unformatted input and output functions or a standard C stream by multiple threads shall not result in a data race.*"

Comment: @ildjarn - Thanks! Is that statement valid for `pthread` as well as `std::thread`?

Comment: @Robᵩ : Yes, synchronization is orthogonal to how a new thread was spawned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to join or the main thread will just exit:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, printInside, 0);
}
/* Join here. */
```

> If I add a cout to the inside of the for loop, it appears to slow it
>   down into working.

Doing `I/O` is generally hard and slow. This gives the other threads enough CPU time to run.

Remember, when using multiple threads **if one calls `exit` they all die**.

#### EDIT

> adding an endl to the end of "inside" does make it work better, but it
>   seems like a cop-out solution. Just wondering why it would be
>   necessary even with the join present.

Output is usually buffered by the standard library. It is flushed in certain circumstances but sometimes you have to do it manually. So even if the threads run and produce output you won't see it unless you flush it.

Comment: I did this I believe. Looks like this...
int main()
{
 pthread_t threads[3];
 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
  pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, printInside, 0);
 }
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
  void* result;
  pthread_join(threads[i],&result);
 }
}

However, it still doesn't get into the thread function.

Comment: @wsnarski Try adding an `endl` to the cout or flush the output manually (`cout.flush`).

Comment: adding an endl to the end of "inside" does make it work better, but it seems like a cop-out solution. Just wondering why it would be necessary even with the join present.

Comment: Adding the cout.flush() after the cout<<"inside" works and the explanation makes sense, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

- You start all threads without any wait, and exit the main thread (thus the whole program) before they start executing.
- Calling [`pthread_join`](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_join.html) before return will wait for the other threads to finish.
- The `cout` helps, as it generates a context switch and a window to the other threads to run.